# how to create a new collection in $out in mongodb based on field names?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to create a new collection based on field names of document in $out.

I have tried bellow command but didn't work.

{ $out: "$fieldName" }

output is: MongoServerError: PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: error with target namespace: Invalid collection name: $fieldName.

one of my documents is like the bellow:

```
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "age" : "24", 
        "gender" : "female"
    }, 
    "fieldName" : "engineer", 
    "name" : "", 
    "value" : NumberInt(1)
}
```

Comment: Try `{ $out: { $getField: "fieldName" } }`. Requires MongoDB version 5 or newer.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have tried it and the error is:MongoServerError: If an object is passed to $out it must have exactly 2 fields: 'db' and 'coll'.  My mongo version is 6.

Comment: Then it could be `{ $out: {db: "db_name", coll: { $getField: "fieldName" }} }`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this.

The `$out` stage specifies a *single* place to direct the output of the entire pipeline to. There is no guarantee that the field names would all specify the same value (and my guess is that you expect that they *don't*). We can see in [the documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) that the `coll` (and `db`) parameters take *string* values as input rather than expressions which resolve to strings.

If I attempt to run the command in the comments it fails with a warning about the wrong type:

```
test> db.version()
6.0.1
test> db.foo.aggregate([{ $out: {db: "db_name", coll: { $getField: "x" }} }])
MongoServerError: wrong type for field (coll) object != string
```

Interestingly, the [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/A3VzZYG-Xad) actually *doesn't* fail. But it looks like that's because it is effectively not evaluating/executing the `$out`. I can put in a [random parameter name](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NPwaLq8brQK) for the stage and it still "works", whereas it normally validates all of the parameters. So I think that the playground here is actually misleading.